# Käse aber auch Wurst

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expression, culture

Just came across that expression used as follows

> Das ist totaler Käse aber ist es auch Wurst.

And wonder what does it mean when something is cheese and sausage at the same time.

Comment: For a useful answer, please give the context, at least the full sentence where you found this expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Use one food idiom, get one free!

These are two idioms put together, which in itself forms a pun.

**The Cheese**

> Das ist (totaler) Käse

is colloquial and means

> it's (complete) nonsense

[This usage dates back to at least 1551](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=%7E%7EKaese&suchspalte%255B%255D). In earlier times, dairy products were virtually everywhere, as such *Käse* but also *Quark* (engl. curd) were cheap and as such gained a negative connotation.

**The sausage**

> Das ist Wurst

is colloquial and means

> it doesn't matter.

[From the same source as above:](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Wurst&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&sp0=rart_ou&sp1=rart_varianten_ou) Since a sausage has two ends, it doesn't matter where you start slicing it.

**Combining this together:**

> That's nonsense, but it doesn't matter (anyway)

Comment: There are many possible explanations on "das ist Wurst", yours is just one of them (maybe less likely). Grimm has a number of them.

Answer (score 5):

> Das ist totaler Käse.

means: it doesn't make sense <sup>[1](https://www.dwds.de/wb/K%C3%A4se#d-1-2)</sup>

> Es ist Wurst.
> <sup>(or Wurscht)</sup>

means: it doesn't matter <sup>[2](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wurst#d-1-3)</sup>

So all together

> Das ist totaler Käse aber ist es auch Wurst?

would be something like:

> That doesn't make any sense. But does it matter?

---

```
1: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Käse#d-1-2
2: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wurst#d-1-3
```

Comment: It isn't (except for the sources). Just saw your answer when I submitted mine.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few explanations to what this means, based on context. However it is worded strangely no matter which explanation is correct.

- [Wurst-Käse-Salat](https://www.bettybossi.ch/de/Rezept/ShowRezept/BB_BBZF130615_0009A-40-de)? (found all over switzerland)
- [Fleischkäse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleischk%C3%A4se)? (contains no cheese)
- [A plate with cheeses and sausages](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/4112861648822933/Kaese-Wurstplatte-schoen-anrichten.html)?
- Sausage with cheesecubes in it?

Comment: I'd say it's obvious to a native speaker that both "Käse" and "Wurst" aren't used in a literal sense, as the other answers indicated.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: In the current state of the question this can only be assumed (even if confirmed by existence of an accepted answer); therefore I left the comment by RalfKleberhoff  in place asking for clarification of the question. For potential downvoters: I don't see a reason to downvote this answer, since the question is to blame for ambiguity.

Comment: @guidot Just in case of any misunderstandings, I didn't downvote this answer ;) I posted the comment above instead of simply downvoting, so to speak.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: I could have made more clear, that this sentence was not directed to you, since downvotes are anonymous even for mods; fixed.

Comment: @guidot I do not see any ambiguity. What should "Das ist totaler Käse" mean, w.r.t. food? This is a non-fitting adjective to describe food or food items. Of course, a guy with a certain mustache could ask if you want the totalen Käse, but that would really be totaler Käse.

Comment: @infinitezero: Your argument doesn't convince me and seems to boil down to *I fail to find another meaning quickly*. What about [this headline in FAZ](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/wissen/netzraetsel/netzraetsel-totaler-kaese-14470405.html)? What about vegan cheese variants and categories in- or excluding those?

Comment: @guidot I'd say this headline uses the same pun. The entire article doesn't explain to me, what totaler Käse is, e.g. compared to veganer Käse, Schmelzkäse, geriebener Käse, Scheibenkäse, ...

Comment: I'd like to point out that the question has been edited since I posted my answer. Now that it reads `das ist totaler käse`, it is very clear to me that it's an idiom, and not about actual foods